# Use Facebook API to search for tags or mentions in posts

Tags: php, facebook, api, search

I was wondering if it is possible to search (and retrieve the content of) a particular user's PUBLIC posts in Facebook using the facebook API - but only those posts between which contain a certain #hastag OR @mention and that fall between 2 timestamps.

We already do similar with our users' Twitter feeds using their api.

Thanks